# How do I get swedish characters in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, character-encoding

I am trying to do the map in `ggplot2` in `R`. I use this function from `rgdal` package:

```
mapa <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("C:/~/SWE_adm_shp"),layer="SWE_adm2")
```

than I do:

```
fortify(mapa)

ggplot(mapa, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "blue", col = "white") +
  coord_map()
```

It works fine but when I look at the

```
head(mapa)
```

I see that the names of the counties dont have the Swedish font (NAME_2)

```
ID_0 ISO NAME_0 ID_1         NAME_1 ID_2      NAME_2   HASC_2 CCN_2 CCA_2   TYPE_2    ENGTYPE_2
0  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    1   Ã–deshÃ¶g SE.OG.OD     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
1  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    2 Ã…tvidaberg SE.OG.AT     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
2  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    3     Boxholm SE.OG.BO     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
3  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    4   FinspÃ¥ng SE.OG.FI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
4  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    5       Kinda SE.OG.KI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
5  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    6  LinkÃ¶ping SE.OG.LI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
  NL_NAME_2 VARNAME_2
0      <NA>      <NA>
1      <NA>      <NA>
2      <NA>      <NA>
3      <NA>      <NA>
4      <NA>      <NA>
```

How to work over that?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Depends on encoding. Maybe setting `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an `encoding` parameter to your read:

```
mapa <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("C:/~/SWE_adm_shp"),layer="SWE_adm2", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

[to specify the encoding](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.2-8/topics/readOGR) of the character set your file uses. It's a good bet that it will be UTF-8.

Comment: It has not helped at all

Comment: @Mateusz1981 That's unfortunate. Thanks for adding your locale information. Since you're on Windows, can you go into a terminal and post the result of `file C:/~/SWE_adm_shp`? It should show its encoding.

Comment: I think I have ANSI som default